# Sum All Numbers of Certain in R Dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, data-science

I have a Dataframe in R that looks like this. [image: Data Frame in R].

How can I sum the time of all the "Customers" individually, and then get another value for all the subscribers? I've tried using `sort` on this data frame to be able to break apart the data that way, but it did not work.

So for example, if I want to know the total amount of Customer Trip Times, I can get that value individually, and likewise, the same thing for subscribers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(trip_time ~ type, df1, FUN = sum)
```